# Record occurrence

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a sample file with below information
Ipaddress , time

ipaddress-1,10:58

ipaddress-1,11:50

ipaddress-1-10:58

ipaddress-2,11:50

ipaddress-2,10:58

ipaddress-2,10:58

Expected output should be
Ipaddress,time,count

ipaddress-1,10:58,2

ipadress-1,11:50,1

ipaddress-2,10:58,2

ipaddress-2,11:50,1

This output is required to understand how many times an ip hit the server at particular time frame .

, I tried using HIVE and was able to get the report using Excel ( ODBC ) . But unable to find the query for the same in PIG.

Answer (score 1):

This script will do the magic:

```
A = load 'test.txt' AS (ip:chararray, time:chararray);
--DESCRIBE A;
--DUMP A;

B = GROUP A BY (ip, time);
--DESCRIBE B;
--DUMP B;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE group, COUNT(A);
DUMP C;
```